# How to change width and height of existing layout params

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-layoutparams

Please consider `ImageView` inside `RelativeLayout` it has some specific layout params for `RelativeLayout`. I need to change the width and height of my `ImageView` programatically according to the screen size.

How can I save all layout parameters but only change width and height

Following code creates empty layout params but I need to save my old params and change only height and width.

```
   imageViewArticleImage.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mScreenSize.y / 3));
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getLayoutParams to get the current layout params.  Change the width and height and go from there.  IF the view is already visible, call requestLayout to force a new layout pass.

Comment: How can I change width and height if existing layout params after `getLayoutParams` ?

Comment: By assigning to them.  Width and height are public member variables of LayoutParams.  You can assign them to either a pixel value or to WRAP_CONTENT or MATCH_PARENT.

Comment: I cannot do this on existing layout params

Comment: Yes you can.  I just did it this morning.          ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParamsOverlay = mOverlayImage.getLayoutParams();
          layoutParamsOverlay.width = (int) (mRemoteOverlayImage.getWidth() * scaleFactor);
          layoutParamsOverlay.height = (int) (mRemoteOverlayImage.getHeight() * scaleFactor);

Comment: Thanks I will try. I have been searching for some method like setter)