# RelativeLayout LayoutParams incorrect scaling

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

I have a Relative Layout within an XML file with an ImageView element which contains both width and height for an image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tankHeight"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/tank_progress" />
```

I then try and dynamically change the height (only height, not width) of the image when the method is called in its class, as follows...

```
public void updateTank() {
    ImageView myTank = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tankHeight);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) 
    myTank.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = 350 - 35;
    myTank.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

However, when this method is called, the image appears to scale by the specified amount in both height **and** width, when I only want to reduce the height by 35 pixels. My understanding is that this may be due to using a relative layout, but I am not sure how to overcome the issue, so that I can programmatically change the height only. From reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326892/how-to-change-width-and-height-of-existing-layout-params) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747123/layoutparams-not-changing), I had thought the method was set up correctly, so am unsure why it is displaying differently than intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `ScaleType` for an `ImageView` is `FIT_CENTER`. What this means is that the source image will be scaled so that you can see the entire thing, regardless of the view's aspect ratio... so even though your *ImageView* is probably only changing its height, the *image content* is being scaled in both dimensions despite only having the view height change.

Try setting `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` on your ImageView tag. This will allow you to resize the view without re-scaling the image contents.

More info on scale types: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/android-imageview-scaletype-a-visual-guide

Comment: Aha! This appears to be having the desired effect, however, the height is being reduced from the bottom of the image up, instead of 'top-down'. Do you know if there is a way to set preference for which 'end' of the image, the pixels are removed from?

Comment: Hm, I would have guessed that you'd see it shrink evenly on both ends. I'm not sure how to solve this new problem, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Changing a view height and/or width requires it to be redrawn, try calling `requestLayout()`. Hope it helps.

```
 public void updateTank() {
    ImageView myTank = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tankHeight);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) 
    myTank.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = 350 - 35;
    myTank.setLayoutParams(params);

    myTank.requestLayout();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should first convert dp to pixel.

```
public int convertDpToPixel(float dp) {
    Context context = getContext();
    if (context == null) {
        return 0; // context should never be a null
    }
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    return (int) (dp * ((float) metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
}
```

and then you can call

```
myTank.getLayoutParams();
params.height = convertDpToPixel(350) - convertDpToPixel(35);
myTank.setLayoutParams(params);
```